# How to improve speed for IPad IOS 8 app calling REST web services

Tags: ios, ipad, rest

There are certain calls that are made from IOS to a REST site. Have serious issues in first few initial calls to REST service (around 6). Did a test run 4 times with total response time to be 30,25, 28 and 44 secs respectively.
Tested the REST service by itself at Fiddler and everything looks to respond in less than a sec. Also set up Ipad to run from a fiddler proxy and everything looks to run at acceptable limits.
Wanted to know the reasons for delay or places to investigate further. I also wanted to tell that the network and the REST site do not have IPv6 (AAAA) enabled and not sure how IOS resolves DNS lookups ?

Comment: run with Charles Proxy and look at the timings

Comment: I have a feeling the compression/decompression at few places are taking a lot of time. How could one measure time taken for HTTP Compression at server side and decompression at client side.

Comment: don't know... but, if you have control of the server try turning compression off and see if that helps.